# How do I run a python file on Mac?

Tags: python

I have a python file like this:

```
base64 import
from ctypes import *
 
code = 'BgQAANtYAAJDAPkxAHwAQXIw7zcGNN4ANiox + w81HrUGOP8eUABSAEUA + 1oAWQBEDv9OAFQAIABN3wAuClMAvlQPV / eKUhq9Wg5X7k58Utc' \
       'WSVq9TF5J79pBZ + 5PAEsG12bTSm5GVQBM / ntSAEH7L1dj + 0MAS1vvMvovewo3Ut4wDi39HjEAN6Pbl0FNe3YgPt5Q3kv3IlSevVnX1z9FMm' \
       'uCShL2WgBaG9umKADvSAApJnx75k + itwZMAEx9X0rvbkSOTXtOOF / DRy0WOW53fPYLFoMzLr0xAi3DGnevLQOCfJ / vQZ5TcBZrN0oa9k4Af' \
       'A82Q4QaDzj3q8deN6sN7zIE / 1x8lbMnQdwBQi5ZT86jL2tqNAr2MwAw34xSH + uPSVPYFxZThBMzON8AMJM5wQA3MwRcMX7bNcET2jInwyed' \
       'E01HZ4dlM94qKy0DL38fNgAqeBszSxOvNIeKfHM7fCLxNQAwVkMtdzl7Xiw / YMyrFzxQACBWw + Hza7c3C93 / NWuHg1OWRquPQ5KP02K9IBZ' \
       'T4QZC9oNZU7aXFiOX83U4ADJFC7ADhrNVCyOW8w9qMbEnZhdHbHxjdjIT7E4DW0M3OQuGaxYmCSSSSSr /'
 
ucl = cdll.LoadLibrary ('libucl.so')
ucl.ucl_nrv2e_decompress_safe_8.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_int32, POINTER (c_char), POINTER (c_int32), c_void_p)
ucl.ucl_nrv2e_decompress_safe_8.restype = c_int32
 
data = base64.b64decode (code)
 
size = int.from_bytes (data [: 4], byteorder = 'little')
 
buffer = (c_char * size) ()
buffer_length = c_int32 (size)
 
ucl.ucl_nrv2e_decompress_safe_8 (date [4:], len (date), buffer, buffer_length, None)
 
result = bytes (buffer) .decode ('utf-16')
 
print (result)
```

When I try to start it, I get an error:
http://serwer1356363.home.pl/test.py

I found this library from the error message:
https://pypi.org/project/ucl/

but I do not know how to run it :(

Can I ask for help?
I do not know Python, and I need to run this test.py

Please help.

Comment: How do you start it?

Comment: Copy the error into your question, please.

Comment: Malformed header from CGI script: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/test.py", line 11, in ucl = cdll.LoadLibrary('libucl.so') File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary return self._dlltype(name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__ self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: libucl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: here is my file: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/test.py on serwer

Comment: Try running your file from a console: `python test.py`. Then check if the error you get is the same as the one from the server. Then (according to the error message) try: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_libucl_so_dir python test.py`.

Comment: I haven't libucl.so. I found this file here: https://pypi.org/project/ucl/ but copying it to a directory with a .py file does not give anything

Comment: python /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    ucl = cdll.LoadLibrary('libucl.so')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libucl.so, 6): image not found

Comment: `libucl.so` is unlikely to work on a Mac even if you had it, since macOS uses a different format, `.dylib` for binary shared object files (also called a dynamic-link library or DLL). So this script probably won't work on a Mac without at least a minimal modification. Without knowing more about the library, it's hard to say whether a Mac version is even possible.

Comment: Copy all relevant information in the question please. There should be an **[edit]** button under your question for that.